# Unix command to stop weblogic server on unix machine using putty from windows

Tags: unix

I am fresher in a software company. I am a beginner in unix. For tomorrow's CR (regarding server patching), I need to stop and start server. I am given a doc in which its given that I need to go in dir- `*.../bin` and execute command `./xxx.server start` command to start server but they have not given the step to stop server. My question is will the command `./xxx.server stop` work to stop server?

xxx.server is present inside bin dir of machine.

Comment: no..its production server, so bit scared in trying untill unless i am sure.

Comment: Ask a question to your colleagues. They probably know more than us about that one

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea for you to work on a production server given your freshman status in the company and your limited knowledge of the tools? I second litelite's suggestion to coordinate yourself with more experienced coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stop it with the parameter stop. You can look inside the script with a listing command like 'less' or 'more' or 'cat', like:

```
more ./xxx.server
```

Then you should find entries with start and stop ( and normally also status).

xxx.server should be a simple script, mostly as shell script, sometimes with a little WLST.
Normally oracle distribute their own start/stop scripts like startWebLogic.sh (to start the admin console) or startManagedWebLogic.sh to start a managed server. But most people write their own start stop scripts. So, if you want to do it right, you should inspect the xxx.server script and/or ask for documentation.